# Не работает pylint в VS code

Tags: python, debian, visual-studio-code, pylint

В Virtual Studio code я пытаюсь установить pylint, прописав в терминале:

```
python3.9 -m pip install pylint
```

И он выдает у меня это:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pylint in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.7.2)
```

И pylint так и не заработал

Comment: а устанавливаете вы от пользователя? он же вам английским по черному пишет, что не имеет прав писать в каталог site-packages

Comment: попробовал от пользователя, но он теперь только это: Requirement already satisfied: pylint in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.7.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил данную проблему, установивнужную версию питона(python-3.10.0) для текущей версии Debian(11 версия)